# Where are web services in three-tier architecture in c#

Tags: asp.net, web-services, architecture, three-tier

Where are web services typically found in three-tier architecture? What are some guildines for adding a new layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you go by the definition [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article71.aspx), the webservice would be between the Business Access Layer and the Presentation Layer.  It is simply a transport between the two layers.  Your webservice could contain the Business Access logic but I don't think that is good design.

Answer (score 1):

Web services usually, in fact, ARE middle tier. Client calling web services calling a storage (i.e. database) is a general pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends, are you using them for Tier communication? are you setting up public facing web services? etc.

If you are using them for Tier communication they exist as inner layers at the tier level.

If you are making a public facing web service(as in out side of the application), then they are at the UI layer, depending on your needs this could be the same project as your UI or it's own.

Answer (score 0):

You start by mixing up layers with tiers; they are not the same. You don't provide any information about your application which makes it impossible for people to answer you anyway.

I strongly recommend you to read some books about enterprise architecture; Fowler is a good author.